# For what values $\alpha$ does the iteration of $e^{-\alpha x}$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

> For what values of $\alpha >0$ will the fixed point iteration $x_{k+1}  =  g(x_k)$ converge for $g(x)=e^{-\alpha x}$ assuming that $x_0= [0,1]$.

Would it suffice to find the derivative of say $h(x) = g(x) - x$ and if that is less than $1$ it is good?

Comment: Where is $\alpha$?

Comment: The derivative of $h$ is negative everywhere hence it can bring no information. What do you think a condition on $g$ would be, which ensures convergence of $(x_k)$?

Comment: If the answer below was helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating a special case of the exponential map:

$$g_\lambda(x)=e^{\lambda\cdot x}$$

for $\lambda=-a$, so let's assume that $\lambda\neq 0$. The fixed points of $g_\lambda$ are found using the Lambert $W$ function as:

$$
\begin{align}
g_\lambda(x)&=x\Rightarrow\\
e^{\lambda\cdot x}&=x\Rightarrow\\
x\cdot e^{-\lambda\cdot x}&=1\Rightarrow\\
-\lambda\cdot x\cdot e^{-\lambda\cdot x}&=-\lambda\Rightarrow\\
-\lambda\cdot x&=W(-\lambda)\Rightarrow\\
x&=\frac{W(-\lambda)}{-\lambda}
\end{align}
$$

Checking the derivative at these fixed points:

$$
\begin{align}
\lvert g_\lambda'(x)\rvert&=\lvert\lambda\cdot e^{\lambda\cdot \frac{W(-\lambda)}{-\lambda}}\rvert\\
&=\lvert\lambda\cdot e^{-W(-\lambda)}\rvert\\
&=\lvert\lambda\cdot\frac{W(-\lambda)}{-\lambda}\rvert\\
&=\vert-W(-\lambda)\rvert\\
\end{align}
$$

By L. Euler's Theorem ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)) the iterated exponential of base $e^{\lambda}$ converges, provided:

$$
\begin{align}
e^{-e}&\le e^\lambda\le e^{\frac{1}{e}}\Leftrightarrow\\
-e&\le \lambda\le \frac{1}{e}\\
\end{align}
$$

Then (excluding the end points, which need to be checked separately),

$$
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{e}&\lt -\lambda\lt e\Leftrightarrow\,\,\,\text{($W$ monotone in range)}\\
W\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)&\lt W(-\lambda)\lt W(e)\Leftrightarrow\\
-1&\lt W(-\lambda)\lt 1\,\,\,\text{(special values of $W$)}\Leftrightarrow\\
\lvert -W(-\lambda)\rvert&\lt 1
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the iterates of $g_\lambda$ will converge by fixed point iteration, provided:

$$-\frac{1}{e}\lt -\lambda= \alpha\lt e$$

and provided the seed value $x_0$ similarly satisfies:

$$e^{-e}\le x_0\le e^{\frac{1}{e}}$$

The case $\alpha=0$ gives the trivial iterates of base 1, so it is omitted.

The case $\alpha=e$ implies $\lambda=-\alpha=-e$ and then $g_\lambda$ will iterate the exponential of base $e^{-e}$, which is known to converge (by Euler, above).

The case $\alpha=-\frac{1}{e}$ implies $\lambda=-\alpha=\frac{1}{e}$ and then $g_\lambda$ will iterate the exponential of base $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, which is also known to converge (again by Euler).

Concluding, the iterates of $g_{-\alpha}(x)=e^{-\alpha\cdot x}$ will converge, **iff** $\alpha\in [-\frac{1}{e},e]$ and $x\in[e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$.

You can deduce the answer now by looking at your question's restrictions for $\alpha$ and $x$.